# Accelerate very time consuming method for DataTable

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I am working on a solution where I have a very time consuming method (GetArbeitsplaene) and I have no idea to accelerate  it. I have a SQL 2008 R2 Express Edition DB for my data. In one table I have 100.000 entries. Here my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the arbeitsplaene.
/// </summary>
private void GetArbeitsplaene()
{
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Arbeitsplan", typeof(List<Arbeitsplan>));
    dTable.Columns.Add(col);

    for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dTable.Rows[i];
        string materialnummer = Convert.ToString(row[1]);

        if (arbeitsplaeneTable == null)
        {
            SQLHelperClass.CreateTable(cn, "ARBEITSPLAENE", ref arbeitsplaeneTable);
        }

        DataRow[] select = arbeitsplaeneTable.Select("Material Like '" + materialnummer + "'");
        List<Arbeitsplan> list = Converter.ConvertDataRowToArbeitsplaene(select);

        dTable.Rows[i].SetField("Arbeitsplan", list);
    }

    // very important, otherwise the changes of the images will be tracked.
    dTable.AcceptChanges();
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the data row to arbeitsplaene.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="select">The select.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<Arbeitsplan> ConvertDataRowToArbeitsplaene(DataRow[] select)
{
    List<Arbeitsplan> list = new List<Arbeitsplan>();

    for (int i = 0; i < select.Count(); i++)
    {
        Arbeitsplan plan = new Arbeitsplan();
        DataRow row = select[i];
        plan.Material = Convert.ToString(row[0]);
        plan.Vrg = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
        plan.Steu = Convert.ToString(row[2]);
        plan.Kurztext_Vorgang = Convert.ToString(row[3]);
        plan.Arbeitsplatz = Convert.ToString(row[4]);
        plan.LstArt = Convert.ToString(row[5]);
        plan.Kostenstelle = Convert.ToString(row[6]);
        list.Add(plan);
    }

    return list;
}

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">Name of the table.</param>
    /// <param name="table">The table.</param>
    public static void CreateTable(SqlConnection cn, string tableName, ref DataTable table)
    {
        string sql = "select * from " + tableName;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter tempAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        SqlCommandBuilder tempcb = new SqlCommandBuilder();
        tempcb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
        tempcb.DataAdapter = tempAdapter;
        table = new DataTable();
        tempAdapter.Fill(table);
    }
```

So I need to run the for loop 100.000 times and this takes time. How can I improve my code to be faster?

Thanks,
TRO

Comment: In the call to `SQLHelperClass.CreateTable` you are providing `"ARBEITSPLAENE"` as parameter for table-name and that does not seem to change, so in each iteration of your `for-loop` you `select *` from that same table, seems like you should rewrite that method to only select it once; ie do that `select` outside of the loop and move it out of the method.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste That table is loaded just one time, but the test for its existence is executed in every loop, but you are right, these lines should be moved outside the loop

Comment: ah yes, silly me just ignored the `if` *facepalm*

Comment: However I really don't know what will be the result of storing a List(Of Arbeitsplan) in a field. Have you tried to compile/run this code?

Comment: Uhm I think that this code cannot work at the start. The DataType of a column cannot be a List(Of Arbeitsplan). See [DataColumn.DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: You a right, I removed the if(). Yes, the code is running, unfortunately slow :-( 
I have a nested object I want to store. So the base object has a List of Arbeitsplaene.

Comment: Sure, it works! You can add a List to a DataColumn and add it to a DataRow.